# How to convert I420 frames to BGRA format with gst-launch-1.0?

Tags: gstreamer, video-conversion, gst-launch

I had a raw video file named video.i420 based on I420 format.
And I tried to convert it into BGRA format using gst-launch-1.0:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=video.i420 ! videoparse width=1920 height=816 format=2 framerate=24/1 ! videoconvert ! videoparse format=12 ! filesink location=video.bgra
```

But the output file video.bgra sized only 48 bytes larger than the source file.

Then I played the video.bgra with the followed command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=video.bgra ! videoparse width=1920 height=816 format=2 framerate=24/1 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

and it's the same as playing the source file.

What's wrong with the pipeline I created for format conversion? And why didn't it convert as I expect？

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

`gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=video.i420 ! videoparse width=1920 height=816 format=i420 framerate=24/1 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=bgra ! filesink location=video.bgra`

I have changed the magic numbers to human readable formats. Just for readability, it should work with numbers as well.

Aside from that. What is required is to tell `videoconvert` a definitive video format. I think the `videoparser` just parses data, but does not enforce specific caps on its predecessor element.